# Flask synchronize GET request

Tags: python, flask

I have the following GET request:

```
@app.route('/change_directory_name', methods=['GET'])
def change_directory_name():
    if "_" in BASE_DIRECTORY_NAME:
        return "Directory name exist"
    else:
        change_directory_name()
        return "Createing new directory name"
```

I guess `Flask` enable multiple requests, So if "request1" change the directory name and before that "request2" try to change the directory name again.

How can I make this code synchronized between all HTTP requests?

Comment: You could wrap the call to `change_directory_name` (and the test, if necessary) in a lock? If it's already locked, don't invoke it again https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock -- or you could record the last time it was changed, and only allow changes at least 5s apart (which would also handle an excessive number of changes to the directory name)

Comment: I don't think locking would help here. File system operations are atomic, they succeed or they fail. They can fail for any reason. For example, some process - *anything*, not necessarily only another request on your webserver - was faster and has already renamed or removed the file. Don't try to "serialize" your webserver to avoid errors, that's pointless. Errors can happen any time. Expect them, handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in logic that checks if

> "Directory name exist"